# Is it possible to extract JDK system module and use it as a standalone application module/JAR file?

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, java-platform-module-system

## Issue

I am using AdoptOpenJDK's JRE 11* to run my application. This application uses JavaFX which needs JDK's system module called jdk.unsupported.desktop. This module is not present in mentioned JRE. I was wondering if it is possible **to extract this single module from SDK and include it in non-modularized application**.

*Adopt is releasing not only JDKs but also JREs

## What I've tried

I've built custom JRE including missing module using jlink and it solved my problem. However, I would like to still use pre-built Adopt JRE instead of custom JRE which I need to create by myself.

## Question

Is it possible to "extract" one module from JDK and use it in non-modularized application as an application module or regular "3rd party" jar?

Comment: What version do you use? Also Javafx has a dependency on `jdk.unsupported.desktop`, but I didn't find a module named `sdk.unsupported.desktop`. Also what is "Adopt JRE 11"? I know about AdoptOpenJDK, which delivers JDK builds, but not JRE builds to my knowledge.

Comment: I am using JavaFX 13, and AdoptOpenJDK's JRE 11. AdoptOpenJDK is also releasing JRE only.

Comment: Did not know it also released JREs. Well, jdk.unsupported.desktop uses internal packages from java.desktop. Not sure if you can deliver your own jdk.unsupported.desktop module.

Comment: See https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1065

Comment: Why do you insist on using an outdated and obviously badly configured JRE for a JavaFX application? Did you consider packaging your application with the EA release of jpackage and the most recent version of the JDK which would avoid your current problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any "official" way to convert a platform module to a standalone JAR. But I believe you can just unzip the file `jdk-11/jmods/jdk.unsupported.desktop.jmod` and repackage it into a JAR file.

- Copy `jdk-11/jmods/jdk.unsupported.desktop.jmod` to a temporary file `jdk.unsupported.desktop.zip`
- Unzip `jdk.unsupported.desktop.zip`
- Zip the classes in the directory `jdk.unsupported.desktop/classes` to `jdk.unsupported.desktop.jar`

Now if you put `jdk.unsupported.desktop.jar` to classpath, it should work with JRE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I have other question about java.desktop module - if I want to understand deeply the module system and will try for educational purpose only to extract/separate "javax.sound" part of that java.desktop module to create my own javax.sound module to use in javafx application which dont need entire java.desktop module - how to do it? I tried first to recompile module-info.java having expected changes there, but I have no success yet ... yes, I know that its only academic debate as I cant redistribute this probably anywhere, am I right?

modified module-info.java (decompiled by javap) is this: (dont know about imports, I added them and left there also more requires than needed now, but my javac command-line complains still...

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.sound.midi.spi.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.spi.*;
import com.sun.media.sound.*;


module javax.sound {
  requires java.base;
  requires java.prefs;
  requires transitive java.datatransfer;
  requires transitive java.xml;

  exports javax.sound.midi;
  exports javax.sound.midi.spi;
  exports javax.sound.sampled;
  exports javax.sound.sampled.spi;

  uses javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiDeviceProvider;
  uses javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiFileReader;
  uses javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiFileWriter;
  uses javax.sound.midi.spi.SoundbankReader;
  uses javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader;
  uses javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileWriter;
  uses javax.sound.sampled.spi.FormatConversionProvider;
  uses javax.sound.sampled.spi.MixerProvider;

  provides  javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiDeviceProvider with
    com.sun.media.sound.MidiInDeviceProvider,
    com.sun.media.sound.MidiOutDeviceProvider,
    com.sun.media.sound.RealTimeSequencerProvider,
    com.sun.media.sound.SoftProvider;
  provides  javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiFileReader with
    com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader;
  provides  javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiFileWriter with
    com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileWriter;
  provides  javax.sound.midi.spi.SoundbankReader with
    com.sun.media.sound.AudioFileSoundbankReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.DLSSoundbankReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.JARSoundbankReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.SF2SoundbankReader;
  provides  javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader with
    com.sun.media.sound.AiffFileReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.AuFileReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader,
    com.sun.media.sound.WaveExtensibleFileReader;
  provides  javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileWriter with
    com.sun.media.sound.AiffFileWriter,
    com.sun.media.sound.AuFileWriter,
    com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter,
    com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileWriter;
  provides  javax.sound.sampled.spi.FormatConversionProvider with
    com.sun.media.sound.AlawCodec,
    com.sun.media.sound.AudioFloatFormatConverter,
    com.sun.media.sound.PCMtoPCMCodec,
    com.sun.media.sound.UlawCodec;
  provides  javax.sound.sampled.spi.MixerProvider with
    com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider,
    com.sun.media.sound.PortMixerProvider;
}
```

this dont work yet: javac -p %JAVA_HOME\jmod% module-info.java

```
module-info.java:1: error: package javax.sound.midi is not visible
import javax.sound.midi.*;
                  ^
  (package javax.sound.midi is declared in the unnamed module, but module javax.sound does not read it)
module-info.java:2: error: package javax.sound.midi.spi is not visible
import javax.sound.midi.spi.*;
                       ^
  (package javax.sound.midi.spi is declared in the unnamed module, but module javax.sound does not read it)
module-info.java:3: error: package javax.sound.sampled is not visible
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
                  ^
  (package javax.sound.sampled is declared in the unnamed module, but module javax.sound does not read it)
module-info.java:4: error: package javax.sound.sampled.spi is not visible
import javax.sound.sampled.spi.*;
```

Comment: well, I somewhat managed to rebuild javax.sound as module from sources, having 2 tiny changes in one deprecated class and one internal reference

Comment: Maybe you should post this as a question which links to this one to get better answers / visibility?